# get specific child using jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

i have this simple example to illustrate my problem:
this is a html page test.html :

```
<body>

        <div class="partA">
            part a
        </div>
        <script></script>
        <div class="partB">
            part b 
        </div>
        <div class="partC">
            part c
        </div>
        <div class="parthh">
            <div>
                part b 2 
            </div>

            <div class="partD">
                part d
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
```

and this is my code java :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new File("C:\\Users\\HC\\Desktop\\dataset\\test.html"), "UTF-8");

    Elements el = doc.select("body > div:eq(1)");

    System.out.println(el.toString());

}
```

the problem that tag 'script'  or other tags came before my diserd tag(the second div in this case ) prevent the good execution of code , and the returned result is empty .

please how can i ignore those undisered tags and get the specific one .

Comment: Do I unserstand you correctly that you need div class="partB"? Try this `Element current = doc.select("div.partB").first();  String text = current.text();`

Comment: no i dont want call it by its classeName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't the selector `body > div:nth-of-type(2)` is what you looking for?

Comment: it work now , by using nth-of-type :) , thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can remove all the `script` tags from your `HTML`:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new File("C:\\Users\\HC\\Desktop\\dataset\\test.html"), "UTF-8");
Elements el = doc.select("script");
for (Element e : el) {
    e.remove();
}
el = doc.select("body > div:eq(1)");
System.out.println(el.toString());
```

Now your doc won't contain that tag, and you'll get the desired output.

Comment: ok i'll clean the bloc of body from any script or css code :/ then i'll try again . thanks TDG